# Displaying error and success messages using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, session, input

I have created a form which helps in signing up into a account. Now when the signing up is successfull I direct the page to login.php and display a flash message.

However this should happen when the user clicks from signin.php.(I am at signin.php)

code at signin.php is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['firstName'])   ||
    isset($_POST['lastName'])   ||
    isset($_POST['email'])      ||
    isset($_POST['password'])   ||
    isset($_POST['confirmedPassword']))
{
    if(empty($_POST['firstName'])   ||
        empty($_POST['lastName'])   ||
        empty($_POST['email'])      ||
        empty($_POST['password'])   ||
        empty($_POST['confirmedPassword']))
    {
        $_SESSION['error']="Please Fill out all the fields";
        header("Location:signin.php");
        return;
    }else{
        if($_POST['password']!=$_POST['confirmedPassword']){
            $_SESSION['error']="Passwords Don't match Retry";
            header("Location:signin.php");
            return;
        }else{
            $_SESSION['success']="Account successfully created.Login Now!!";
            header("Location:login.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Code at login.php is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
    echo('<p style="color:green">'.$_SESSION['success']."</p>");
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
?>
<form>
    <div><label for="Email">Email</label></div>
    <div><input name="email"id="Email"></div>
    <div><label for="password">Password</label></div>
    <div><input name="Password"id="password"></div>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
<div>Don't have an Account?<a href="signin.php">Create Account</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am successfully being redirected but the success message is not being displayed.

Comment: Your conditional statements are contradicting themselves.

Comment: how are they contradicting?

Comment: First you're checking if they're set then if they're empty.

Comment: if i don't do that whenever i go to signin.php the error message get printed

Comment: I do think you should read what `empty()` does [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: `login.php` Does not have a `session_start()`

Comment: If i wont use the isset line for every get request to signin.php the error message get printed.I only want the error to pop up when it is a post request to signin.php and the fields are empty

Comment: `<form>` defaults to a GET method when POST isn't implied and you're using POST arrays. I would start by enabling error reporting now.

Comment: why don't you just say `if isset(value && value &&....){do some stuff} else {do some error handling}`

Comment: I also don't see the named input that's associated with `$_POST['confirmedPassword']` and others. There are far too many errors made in what you're trying to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start()

if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
    echo '<p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION['success'] . "</p>";
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo '<p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p>";
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
?>
<form>
    <div><label for="Email">Email</label></div>
    <div><input name="email"id="Email"></div>
    <div><label for="password">Password</label></div>
    <div><input name="Password"id="password"></div>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
<div>Don't have an Account?<a href="signin.php">Create Account</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to start the session_start() method, also make sure your form submission method is correct.

Comment: session_start() should be used before any output (including html)

Comment: I forgot to use session_start() at the beginning!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
session_start()

if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
    echo '<p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION['success'] . "</p>";
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo '<p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p>";
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
?>
```

Comment: did you mean to do `unset($_SESSION['success']);` on both conditions

Comment: i thought so - tried to edit it for you but it was less than 10 characters! lol :-)